# Why Would Someone Intentionally Get Consumed by a Dark Farungen?

Tags: magic, humans

I know that this question **demands** answers, so here we go:
Creatures of living elements, called Farungen, exist in this world, which is a medieval fantasy-type. Most Farungen keep to themselves in remote areas (Fire Farungen in volcanos, Ice Farungen in the arctic north, Plant Farungen in jungles, you get the idea right?). Dark Farungen represent the ancient void, being living vacuums formed of darkness.

Since no vacuum is perfect, Dark Farungen have life and minds of their own, but they are incomplete. Because of this, Dark Farungen seek out and engulf living things, and in the process annihilate both themselves and their victim. The result is a new creature that resembles the victim, its physical and mental traits a hodgepodge of both the Farungen and the creature it consumed.

If this doesn't make sense, this is how monsters and supervillains are created; those odd features are the result of the Farungen's darkness infusing (and twisting) the physical, mental, and even spiritual traits of the victim. So, my question is **why would someone intentionally get consumed by a Dark Farungen?**

Please tell me if my tags are wrong, I did my best guess here....

Comment: Haver you *seen* humans? Overall there are people who'd do anything, regardless of how dangerous or logical it is. The recent pandemic has supplied us with plenty of examples of people endangering themselves and others by exposing themselves to COVID-19.

Comment: I know that there are people who'd do anything VLAZ, but I need a _why_. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Power and Immortality:

Being destroyed sucks, true. But in a medieval world, even becoming half of a powerful creature is appealing for someone who has nothing. Perhaps they believe the resulting creature will carry out plans of revenge. Perhaps they are enticed by a belief that they retain more control and existence than they really do. But power is seductive, especially to those with none.

Further, it's a tough world out there. A lot of people are dying of a lot of diseases, or starvation, or old age. A monster is strong and healthy, while dying is imminent and permanent. If you don't believe in a merciful god taking you to a better place, or that YOU personally aren't getting there, then this is a way to stay alive - sort of.

Look at vampires. Everyone knows vampires lose their souls, but there doesn't seem to be a shortage of volunteers. Why? Vampires are powerful. Vampires are immortal (we'll ignore the high mortality rates due to violence, sunlight, etc.). Even a rich noble who believes he's offended his god and is going to "hell" might prefer a half-life over damnation or dissolution. A few "successful" Farungen (like powerful supervillains) around and people will start thinking it's a god alternative to whatever poor alternatives life has to offer.

Comment: Very insightful! Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 4):

If the nature of dark farungens is known, this can be a form of suicide, with the added bonus that the new creature may seek out revenge on those who have wronged (or "wronged") the suicidal person.

If it is unknown, the legend is probably that the victim receives great powers at a great price.  Someone determined to do something -- avenge his family, grow immensely rich, claim the throne from the king -- may find the bargain quite reasonable.  (And once they are killed they can hardly tell people otherwise; it looks like they survived in twisted form.)

Comment: Great answer, thank you!